# Multiple remotes setup, how to delete merged branches only from single remote?

Tags: git

I have a repo with many remotes setup because we are using the [Forking Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow)

I typically clean all the merged branches from the origin repo every quarter. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to clean the merged branches from the individual remotes.

```bash
git branch -r --merged <how can i target a specific remote?> |
  grep -v "develop" |
  grep -v "master" |
  grep -v "pr" |
  sed -r 's/(remote1|remote2|remote3|remote4)\///' |
  xargs git push -d origin
```

The idea here is to list all the merged branches, filter out `develop`, `master`, `pr` and remove `origin/`, then `git push -d`

the problem I'm having is I don't know how to target only a specific remote for deletion. Each time I run this command, it lists all the branches from each remote. Then running the command outputs an error

```bash
error: unable to delete '<branch-name>': remote ref does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the output of `git branch -r --merged` includes the remote name, you can use `grep` (etc) to filter by remote. E.g. to see only those branches in the `remote1` remote:

```
git branch -r --merged | grep remote1/
```

Putting that together with what you have -- and simplifying things a bit -- we get:

```
git branch -r --merged |
  grep remote1/ |
  grep -vE 'develop|master|pr' |
  sed 's/[^/]*\///' |
  xargs git push -d remote1
```

---

If you're getting errors, replace `xargs` with `echo xargs` so you can see the generated command line without running it.